# rails 2.8 restful routes with no models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I make a controller restful when it does not have a model? I have the following controller called programs, and I want it to be restful so that:

rake routes | grep programs

will show me a complete list of methods. Currently I only have:

```
new_programs GET    /programs/new(.:format)                        {:controller=>"programs", :action=>"new"}
      edit_programs GET    /programs/edit(.:format)                       {:controller=>"programs", :action=>"edit"}
           programs GET    /programs(.:format)                            {:controller=>"programs", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /programs(.:format)                            {:controller=>"programs", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /programs(.:format)                            {:controller=>"programs", :action=>"destroy"}
                    POST   /programs(.:format)                            {:controller=>"programs", :action=>"create"}
```

I have added map.resource :programs to my routes file, I want /program/:id as well

Comment: Did you mean Rails 2.3.8? I don't think there was a version 2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've used `resource` when you needed to use `resources`. Try changing your routes to:

```
map.resources :programs
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going off the definition here. But it is possible. model is not necessary.just create the resources line and create the controller. Inside the controller's actions, define the code you want to put.